# RESTful webservice form-data POST request - replace hardcoded values for variables that can be set prior to test suite execution

Tags: xml, web-services, rest, post

I'm new at testing REST webservices and this is the scenario I'm facing:
I send a POST request (form-data) to a URL http://webservices.something/something.php
with the following elements:

.user

.password

.request (the request is XML)

and I'd like to replace the hardcoded data in the XML for variables, like this:

```
<DepartureDateTime>2016-12-16</DepartureDateTime> 
<OriginLocation LocationCode="AEP"/> 
<DestinationLocation LocationCode="COR"/> 
</OriginDestinationInformation>
```

to

```
<DepartureDateTime>{DepartureDateTime}</DepartureDateTime> 
<OriginLocation LocationCode={OriginLoc}/> 
<DestinationLocation LocationCode={DestinationLoc}/> 
</OriginDestinationInformation>
```

But I can't seem to figure it out since the XML fields I like to modify are already inside another field (request) in the HTTP message.

I'm using Postman and SOAPui for the tests.
Any ideas/suggestions?
Sorry if it's not very clear, and thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Try use request body in postman in raw format with 'application/xml'.
More in the [docs](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests)